# Problem on linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $ u=\langle u_1,u_2,u_3\rangle $ be any vector in the vector space $V=\Bbb R^3$. Show that the equation $ u = \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3 $ has a unique solution for the following base $ V =\Bbb R^3$.

**Try:**

To show that, let's consider two solutions, these are $$u=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3\quad \text{and}\quad u=\beta_1v_1+\beta_2 v_2+\beta_3 v_3.$$

Then, $$0=u-u=(\alpha_1-\beta_1)v_1+(\alpha_2-\beta_2)v_2+(\alpha_3-\beta_3)v_3.$$

Since $ u $ is linearly independent, since it is a basis for $ V $. We get that, $$\alpha_1-\beta_1=\alpha_2-\beta_2=\alpha_3-\beta_3=0.$$ Then, $\alpha_1=\beta_1,\alpha_2=\beta_2,\alpha_3=\beta_3.$ Therefore, the solution is unique. My proof is right?

Comment: a base is not a vector space, e.g. $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ is not a base.  the collection $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is a basis of $V$. other than that your solution is pretty much fine.

Comment: Thanks for read my answer. I appreciated.

Comment: AS written, the question does not make sense. Did you reproduce it faithfully ?

Comment: The question is mostly about the uniqueness of the representation of a base, as I am a bit entangled with so much definition, I misspelled the question. My mistake.

Comment: What does "has a unique solution for the following base $ V =\Bbb R^3$" mean???

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment made by @CSquared, "Since $u$ is linearly independent, since it is a basis for $V$" doesn't make any sense. You probably meant to say that $(v_1,v_2,v_2)$ are linearly independent.

Furthermore you only showed uniqueness of solution under the assumption of existence. You also need to show that a solution exists!

Comment: I think the existence is quite obvious since $ u $ generates  $(v_1,v_2,v_3) $.

Comment: i believe what @GAmerpasdoa  is trying to say is that $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ spans $V$, since it is a basis, so a solution does indeed exist.

Comment: Yes, what you said. I'm a bit lost with the definitions, it's time to study them a little more. For the rest, thank you very much.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.